# Batch file to append 'Text' from one File to a 'Central Text File'?

Tags: shell, batch-file, window

Batch file to append 'Text' from one File to a 'Central Text File'(Not overwrite text on the main file)?

The following code dosnt copy the contents of 'log2.log' instead it just writes the name of directory 'C:....\LogFiles\log2.log' to the log.txt

@echo "C:....\LogFiles\log2.log" >> "\1xx.1xx.1.xx\c$....\log.txt" 
[image]

Comment: Pluse points for a visual illustration of your problem. Minus points for any indication that you have tried to solve your problem. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you are echoing the name of the file. If you would like the output of a file to be transferred, use the keyword type

```
type "C:....\LogFiles\log2.log" >> "\1xx.1xx.1.xx\c$....\log.txt
```

If you want to append a new line afterwards you can do:

```
echo. >> destination
```

Where you replace destination with the destination text file.

Comment: thannks so much! how would i do a new line after the text has been written?

Comment: I've modified my answer with the line echo. >> file.txt. That can be used to append a new line.